# Can I Save Get Request Data To File?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

Is it possible, using JS/jQuery, to save data from my GET request to file?

So my API request is:

```
var request = Me.api({
    endpoint : endpoint,
    type: 'GET'
});
```

I'd be happy just to save it locally to something like http://local.me.co.uk/data.json

As a bit of background, the purpose is that there can be a lot of data for this API call, and sometimes on mobile, it will not load any of the data - I assume a memory issue but that's beyond my knowledge.

So my idea was save to http://local.me.co.uk/data.json and then process it from there.

Thanks
James

Comment: You cannot save files to the local file system using JS. Your solution seems flawed anyway, as you say this is a workaround for failed attempts to load data, yet the data must be loaded anyway for it to be saved to the local device. You would be better off attempting to solve the issue with the API call - even if it does take some time.

Comment: If you are trying to save data from request made in your client (browser), than answer is No, you cant. This would be possible if your code was running on server via Node.js.

Comment: Thanks for your respective advice.